# C# MVC 4 model changing floating point?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization

I have some problems with globalization and floating points. Intresting thing is if i send data in en-GB and floating point is "." (dot) all seems looks fine

[image: floating point in post and model is thesame]

but when i change culture with coma "," then all going weird :)

[image]

Now in screen above u can see POST sending "0,07" but model give me "7". Any ideas how to fix this problem ?

Tx for answers and ideas :)

Comment: EN-GB uses decimal points as `.` so it will ignore the comma. Thus you're getting `007` as a float: `7.0`. It's not really clear what you're asking, if you want `0,07` to be accepted as a float, then change the culture?

Comment: Like u see on the screens when using number in post is with "." all looks fine when i change lanuage (Culture)on language with "," as float separator POST sending "0,07" but model on enty give me "7"

Comment: Can you show us how and where you set the culture?

Comment: And what culture you used for the floating point formatted by comma

Comment: (pl-PL) Polish culture for example, first ihave method to change culture where i set in the session curent culture and then in globa.asax inprotected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e) i put this culture and this woring of corse i beliwe problem is in the another way :)just o dont know where ... yet

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to set CurrentThread.CurrentCulture because that is the one used for parsing the number.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    }
}
```